# Determining a class in Dolbeault cohomology that defines a principal $\mathbb{C}$-bundle over a compact torus

Tags: complex-geometry, cech-cohomology

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4235739/402997) from MSE

Consider a standard complex torus $\mathbf{T}=\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}\oplus i\mathbb{Z}).$ It could be obtained in another way.

$\mathbf{T}$ is a quotient $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2/\mathbb{C}.$ Here $\mathbb{C}$ is acts on $\mathbb{C}^2$ by multiplication:

$$
z\circ (x,y)=(e^{z}\cdot x, e^{iz}y)\in \mathbb{C}^2.
$$

The bundle $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2\to \mathbf{T}$ is represented by a certain class in Cech cohomology group ${\check{H}}^1(\mathbf{T};H).$ Here $H$ is a complex Lie group isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}.$ This cohomology group is isomorphic to the sheaf cohomology group $H^1(\mathbf{T};\mathcal{O}).$ By Dolbeault's theorem, this group, in turn, is isomorphic to $H^{0,1}_{\overline{\partial}}(\mathbf{T})\cong \overline{T}^\vee.$ Here $\overline{T}^\vee$ is a space of antiholomorphic covectors on the tangent space of $\mathbf{T}$ at zero.

My question is: which class represents the bundle $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^2\to \mathbf{T}?$

Also, is there a geometric way of understanding the answer, i.e., why does a certain covector represent this specific bundle?